# Swift workspace, popover view controller not displaying fields

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, workspace

I am using a Workspace and am trying to display a child viewcontroller as a popup.

If I call the child viewcontroller  as a normal presentation then it display fine, and the field in the viewcontroller displays :

```
let popoverContent = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("purposeController") as! purposeViewController
self.presentViewController(popoverContent, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

If I then try and display this as a popover, the viewcontroller displays, I can tell as I have set the background colour to make it obvious, but the fields in the viewcontroller are not displayed :

```
let popoverContent = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("purposeController") as! purposeViewController
popoverContent.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
popoverContent.popoverPresentationController!.sourceView = sender.myView
self.presentViewController(popoverContent, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I have added a button to the parent viewcontroller, and set it to perform a popover presentation segue for the child viewcontroller, and again the popover appears, but with no fields.

If I use the same configuration in a standalone project, then everything appears as expected.

Any help would be much appreciated as I have been chasing this down for 2 days, and getting no different results.

Comment: Please provide more details about the problem. What are the "fields" that you have in the popover? How are they positioned?

Comment: At the moment I have one label field, it is position at 10, 10.